# If jquery does not find a match, is an error thrown?

Tags: jquery

Will an error be thrown if jquery does not find any items of class box-typical-body?

```
 $('.box-typical-body').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions);
```

If so, then as far as I can tell, the correct code would be:

```
 if ( $( ".box-typical-body" ).length ) {
    $('.box-typical-body').jScrollPane(jScrollOptions);
 }
```

I have tested, and it appears to be so, but am a novice at jquery and want to make sure.

Comment: Are you saying you do get an error , if so what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.box-typical-body')` will always return an object, its just an empty one, so the error throwing will actually depend on if the plugin `jScrollPane` check if the object is empty of not.

So its safer to do it your way to account for all possibilities.

Comment: However, if `jScrollPane` follows the usual jQuery plugin conventions (which I believe it does), then its methods will start by invoking `each()` on your jQuery object, rendering the test unnecessary. Note that a jQuery plugin that doesn't do that is considered as broken.